# What should I do when a Documentation topic "is also being edited by" other users?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, documentation, user-experience

I'm just trying out the Documentation beta, by editing the [JS Hello World examples](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world), but got a big red warning that it is also being edited by others.

**Now what?  I don't know.  It doesn't tell me.**

I expected the UI to explain clearly what "other users editing" *actually means* for me and my in-progress edit, and present some *actionable points* for rectifying the problem, or else just straight-up kick me out if there's nothing I can do.

Instead I get a red box with warning signs, which is UI-speak for "*ABORT MISSION, something is terribly wrong*". The only action shown to me with it is some buttons to *View Their Draft*, which—understandably—shows me that draft, but I don't know what to do with it.  They all seem to be *Unpublished*, and I can't seem to be able to change that, so I don't know why the button bothered to send me there. What did this detour accomplish?

By that point I was confused enough that I abandoned my edit and left, instead of risking an unspecified accident of unknown degree of terribleness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** we've dropped the limit on showing these things down to 30 minutes. That oughta be *much* less distracting and discouraging than the previous default (24-hours). Let's give this a bit more time & see how folks treat it before adding guidance.

---

Heh... This is why we avoided implementing [requests for similar notifications on post edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post) in the past: concern that it might discourage folks from editing when others were just... camping on the edit page.

It's gonna take some time to see how this plays out in docs; we *may* not want to make these notifications as obvious, or we may want to do more to encourage discussion among editors. But for now, here's my advice:

- Unless the timestamp on another edit is *recent*, **just ignore these.** You're on a mission, you see a problem, you're gonna fix it; who knows if those other editors are ever gonna submit their edits.
- If another edit was started in the past few minutes, **take a look and see what they've done.** If they're changing the same thing you were, you can decide whether to keep going or stall for a bit to give them time to finish. This is where such a feature *would* be useful on posts; most of us have at one time or another stepped on each other's toes making obvious edits to new posts, and the same thing happens in docs - but now you have the ability to detect it and avoid wasting effort on (say) fixing typos when someone else is doing the same thing.

Lemme know if this strategy works for you... Or if it doesn't, where it falls over. Eventually, I think we'll want to build this into the UI.

Comment: Is there some kind of time limit on that notification?  I tried editing a popular topic and got five notifications...four of which were dated 23 hours prior.  Seems much more reasonable to cap them to an hour or two at most.

Comment: There is a limit, @Troyen. It's currently set to 86400 seconds, or - as you might surmise from the dates on those you've seen - 24 hours. It's quite possible that is excessive. **Edit:** now 1800 seconds, or 30 minutes. Should see this much less often.